# is it posible to display all the loaded mappings and configs within Struts2 while running?

Tags: debugging, struts2, runtime, struts2-config-browser

I often get confused with various cases of the incorrect config for Struts2. Such as after modified packages or classes.

The bootstrap log of Struts2 shows hardly any detail on loaded mappings.

I want to list all the loaded configures at running time. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Config Browser](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/config-browser-plugin.html).

A nice example is [here](http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2009/6/28/Struts-2-Config-Browser-Plugin--Get-Information-About-Your-Applications-Configuration).

Just be sure to use the same version as your other Struts2 dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could add the config-browser plugin to your development environment.I use this all the time - it makes seeing what Struts thinks is configured an absolute breeze.